# How to get a GtkCellRenderer's GtkTreeViewColumn?

Tags: c, callback, gtk, viewmodel

Some gtk source code sleuthing has lead me to believe the following code can obtain the column in the model where an attribute is stored.

However, to get to this point from a signal handler I need to get a `GtkCellRenderer`s parent `GtkTreeViewColumn`

I don't know how to do this, other than passing the treeview column directly (Which eliminates my ability to include the model that needs to be updated in the first place) or passing the `GtkTreeView` itself which would give me access to the model, but not the `GtkTreeViewColumn`

Quite a complicated problem. Of course if anyone knows a builtin GTK function to go from `GtkCellRenderer` straight to `GtkListStore` that would be much better.

```
void
treeview_combo_edited(GtkCellRendererCombo * widget, gchar * path, gchar * value, GtkListStore * model){
    GtkTreeIter iter;
    gtk_tree_model_get_iter_from_string(GTK_TREE_MODEL(model),&iter,path);
    // How to get GtkCellRenderer's GtkTreeViewColumn to use in line below?
    GSList * attributes = g_object_get(treeviewcolumn,attributes);
    int colnumber = g_slist_nth_data(g_slist_position(g_slist_find(attributes,"text")) - 1);
    gtk_list_store_set
    (
        model,
        &iter,
        colnumber,
        value,
        -1
    );
}
```

**Edit:** It might be possible to pass the treeviewcolumn directly to get both needed variables but I've run into problems getting the cell renderer's attributes. How do I get them at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this API seems to be missing. In my code i use

```
GtkTreeViewColumn *column = gtk_tree_view_column_new();
GtkCellRenderer* renderer = gtk_cell_renderer_text_new();
g_object_set_qdata_full(G_OBJECT(renderer), g_quark_from_static_string("column"), (gpointer)column, NULL);
```

and then later you can use

```
GtkTreeViewColumn* column = (g_object_get_qdata(G_OBJECT(renderer), g_quark_from_static_string("column"));
```

To get the column from a renderer object.

Comment: All right but I'm using glade here and I don't want to waste forever figuring out how to do that in glade...

Comment: I'm just marking this cause I gave up and wrote the signal handlers manually